# where does session save?

Tags: php, session, browser, cookies

I would like to know where PHP session data is saved; is it in client browser? or on the server?

When I disable cookies in my browser setting, PHP can't save session data, but in `php.ini`, I can change the session save path.

Is session data stored on the server or client browser?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The session **data** that you read and write using `$_SESSION` is stored on server side, usually in text files in a temporary directory. They can not be accessed from outside.

The thing connecting a session to a client browser is the session **ID**, which is usually stored in a cookie (see the comments for exceptions to that rule). This ID is, and should be, the only thing about your session that is stored on client side.

If you delete the cookie in the browser, the connection to that session is lost, even if the file on the server continues to exist for some time.

The `session.save_path` variable influences the location *on the server* where the session data is stored. If you are not the server's administrator, it is usually not necessary to change it.

Comment: If cookies are disabled, the session ID is appended to all page requests.

Comment: @Martijn  That is not the default behaviour of session. This need some more code stuff to be done in your side

Comment: Correct, and if cookies are not available, the session ID is passed through URLs and hidden form inputs. This is handled automatically by PHP. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php

Comment: @Shakti Singh: of course, cookies are standerd. Point is you can still use sessions even if users disabled cookies.

Comment: @Shakti Singh it doesn't require any code, you just have to enable session.use_trans_sid in your php.ini or via .htaccess

Comment: @Capsule true, however AFAIK it doesn't manage to add the session ID everywhere - you'll have to pass the session ID manually in Ajax requests, for example. If you use a lot of Ajax, you need to do deep testing to make sure this works.

Comment: @Capsule: It requires to pass the Session ID in URL. That you have to handle across application

Comment: @Pekka Yep, but IE is so buggy at handling cookies in Ajax requets I always pass the session ID if needed when using Ajax ;-)

Comment: @Shakti not necessarily. `session.use_trans_sid` rewrites your HTML output to add the session ID automagically. It just doesn't always work, e.g. with Javascript.

Comment: @Shakti Singh please READ my comment and the URL I provide, most of the work is done by PHP.

Answer (score 13):

It's both! A session saves the actual session information on the server, but gives an identification cookie to the client to know which session belongs to which client. The information in the cookie itself is worthless, but allows the server to identify the client and use the actual session information.

Comment: So it is not both then. Just an id that helps us know who a session belongs to doesn't necessarily mean that the session is stored both on the client side and the server side. Therefore it is not both but on the server but a unique ID is stored in the cookie, and the cookie is stored on the client side.

Answer (score 13):

> Blockquote "Is session data stored on the server or client browser?"

It makes me think of a valet parking system. The valet (server) keeps your car (session data), but he/she gives you a ticket (session id) to hang onto which proves that the car is yours when you need access to it. If you lose your ticket (by deleting your cache, or closing the browser), your car (session data) is as good as gone since you can't prove it's your car anymore.

Okay, it's just an analogy...and breaks down quickly. E.g. you don't actually own your session information like you do your car. And you don't get to drive it away.

Answer (score 4):

Both, the session in the client(browser) is saved as a cookie. This cookie references a session which also resides on the server.

Comment: Not both again. Sessions and Cookies are different. We shouldn't say both. An ID stored in the cookie doesn't suddenly make the cookie a session.

Answer (score 1):

It is stored on the server side to maintain security; but additional cookies could be also stored on the client side.