# cookies and sessions in host

Tags: php, session, cookies

I have the following code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$cexp=time()+(60*60*24*3650);
setcookie('cookie_jamepush','cookie_content',$cexp ,'/');
echo 'cc='.$_COOKIE['cookie_jamepush'];
$_SESSION['user']='hello';
echo 'ss='.$_SESSION['user'];
?>
```

This code works properly for the website it was created for.

However, I have two websites that are running on a common server. The above code works on one, but doesn't work on the other.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: This link may have some info to help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20417642/what-happens-if-session-name-is-same-on-two-different-websites.  You may need to have unique session names for each website to avoid session conflicts.

Comment: Are the two websites on the same web server?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible. You can share cookies only in subdomains.

[Sharing cookies across different domains and different applications (classic ASP and ASP.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781353/sharing-cookies-across-different-domains-and-different-applications-classic-asp)

If you want to use sessions in different hosts, you should make database sessions

Comment: hi to all.when i clear content of my website and upload again problem is solved. thanks a lot