# Session gets mixed up on localhost...?

Tags: php, apache, session, server

I've two projects on my machine(localhost), what happens is, the session of one project is recognized by another project:

The URL of both the projects are:

```
http://localhost/Blog/admin/admin_homepage.php

http://localhost/MyMVC/
```

So when I log into Blog project, I automatically get logged into MyMVC and when I logout of MyMVC, I get logged out from Blog as well.

If someone could explain this behavior(like why this mix up happens?), logically, it would be of great help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20417642/what-happens-if-session-name-is-same-on-two-different-websites?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: You may prefix your session variable. Eg: $_SESSION['blog_user']="john";

Comment: you could run `loalhost1` and `localhost2` this would be more like a real set up. other wise you need to set the session cookie path

Answer (score 0):

Set the path in the session cookie with `session_set_cookie_params` before `session_start`

Comment: you can also check this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php) to save session to specific path