# PHP Sessions not working in FireFox

Tags: php, session, firefox

I am defining a session variable based on $_POST (from page 1) on page 2 off my application like this:

**customer_view.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
// Session Name//
$account_manager_id = $_POST["account_manager_id1"];
$_SESSION['account_manager_id'] = $account_manager_id; 
// this sets variables in the session//
?>
```

and using it again on page three like this:

**category_view.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$account_manager_id = $_SESSION['account_manager_id'];
// Session Name//
// this sets variables in the session//
?>
```

The $account_manager_id session variable passes from page to page and works as required in Chrome, but not in FireFox. The web console on page 3 is only showing the syntax errors being caused by the session variable being undefined in page 3.

Any thoughts?

ADDED code from page one as requested:

```
<form action="customer_view.php" method="post">
    <p>Enter Account Manager ID</p>
<input type="text" name="account_manager_id1" id="account_manager_id1"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: You're re-assigning it. You're best to check if the session is set and/or not empty, then use that session variable you've already assigned in the preliminary page in any subsequent pages thereafter.

Comment: Do you have cookies enabled?

Comment: check FF settings, perhaps you are blocking something ?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I doubt that this is reassignation. In page 3 `$account_manager_id` variable does not exist. OP wants to assign to this varialbe the session value, but it gives error(I guess undefined index?)

Comment: Then the OP still needs to check if it's assigned, is set and not empty. @RoyalBg Sessions are serverside as opposed to cookies.

Comment: @Fred-ii- the OP needs to check this in both pages. However, if the POST is made, then the last page should not give any errors

Comment: @Fred-ii- Session IDs are client-side cookies though (unless you specifically intend some other meaning of storing the SID). So if those are disabled it won't work.

Comment: @ccKep http://stackoverflow.com/a/5593377/ session ID yes I agree but not the session data itself. Session data is stored on the server. Cookies are stored in the client. OP is dealing with sessions here and not cookies.

Comment: _“OP is dealing with sessions here and not cookies.”_ – dealing with the former usually means dealing with the latter as well (remember, `session.use_only_cookies` defaults to `1` from PHP 5.3 on). If the session id does not get passed correctly, then the session will not be picked up on the following page, but a new one will be created. So that is indeed the very first thing one should check when having a problem like this.

Comment: @OP: I tested your code on FF/CHROME/IE and everything checks out.

Comment: @CBroe So, this will depend on OP's PHP version then. If OP's version is older than 5.3 then the defaults are set to `0`? Or, check if it's a newer version and if it's indeed set to `1`. I can't see how Chrome can pick up on it and FF doesn't.

Comment: @Fred-ii- however, if session id cannot be resolved, the information will not be present

Comment: OP needs to post full and actual code. If cookies AND sessions are used interactively (and seperately) plus in conjunction with each other, then I'd suspect client-side cookies, ok; this doesn't add up for me.

Comment: I cleared all cookies from FF and revisited my pages. The PHPSESSID is being stored in FF. Im using PHP 5.4.24. I added additional code to my original post.

Comment: @TechnoCripple What do `session.use_cookies` and `session.use_only_cookies` `session.cache_limiter` `session.cache_expire` `session.cookie_lifetime` show as PHP info?

Comment: @Fred-ii session.use_cookies and session.use_only_cookies are both 'on'; session.cache_limiter = 'nocache'; session.cache_expire = 180; session.cookie_lifetime = 0;

Comment: Are you running this via WWW or localhost? @TechnoCripple

Comment: Are you outputting **anything** before `session_start()`? ("anything" is not limited to php in this case, does your browser get any data (except headers) before session_start?)

Comment: @Fred-ii-I am running it via localhost; ccKep - no Im not outputting anything before the session starts.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the help; the answer below solved the issue in FF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't define the variable in page 1 and you didn't use isset or empty to check the variable is SET or Empty

```
$account_manager_id = '';

if(isset($_POST['name']) $account_manager_id = $_POST["account_manager_id1"];
```