# PHP sessions: isolate subdirectory login system

Tags: php, session, subdirectory

I have a php based software that use a login system with php sessions. I need to replicate this php software in a subdirectory of the same domain in this way:

- /root/phpsoftware1
- /root/phpsoftware1/phpsoftware2

The problem is that if I login in the php software 1 and then try to access the php software 2 the system recognize a valid session when htere is not.

Is it possible to isolate the two directory so that sessions valid for software 1 are not valid for software 2 and vice versa?

Comment: Can't you set the [`session_save_path`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php) to a different location in phpsoftware2?

Comment: One simple trick would be to use different variable names for session for both directories. You could do `$_SESSION["authorized_root"]` VS `$_SESSION["authorized_sub"]` etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set two different session names with `session_name($somename)`. This needs to be called before `session_start()` or `session_register()` in both places and will set the name of the session used in client cookies (the default is `PHPSESSID` otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

You can't set two different sessions for the same client, on one server. PHP Sessions are stored on the server per client (Browser or whichever application is making a request) (See: [where does session save?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593359/where-does-session-save)) .

To achieve what you requested, you could either take Hanky 웃 Panky's approach (Mentioned in the comments of your question), or once the entry point for `/root/phpsoftware/phpsoftware2` has been reached, `unset()` your session key, so a new one can be created (Note that this will also kill the session for `/root/phpsoftware1`, so I would rather take Hanky 웃 Panky's approach)

Hope it helped a bit. Lemme know if you need more elaboration.